# AngularJS Binding Values to NgShow and NgHide

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use an array to show and hide divs using ng-show and ng-hide.  It doesn't seem to work consistently.  When I check the values using the console, they are correct, but they aren't reflected correctly in the HTML.

```
<div class="directionsContent" ng-show="showvars.directions" ng-hide="!showvars.directions">
    <h1 class="directionsTitle">DIRECTIONS TO:</h1>
    <h3>{{directions.title}}</h3>
    <div id="directionsPanel"></div>
</div>
```

The function used is:

```
$scope.ShowMobile = function (showsection) {

    console.log(showsection)
    for (prop in $scope.showvars) {
        console.log(prop, $scope.showvars[prop])
        if (showsection != "return" && showsection != "info") {
            $scope.showvars[prop] = false;
        }
    }

    switch (showsection) {
        case "explore": 
            $scope.showvars.explore = true;
            break;
        case "directions":
            $scope.showvars.explore = true;
            $scope.showvars.directions = true;
            break;
        case "tourlist":
            $scope.showvars.explore = true;
            $scope.showvars.tourlist = true;
            break;
        case "tourdetail":
            $scope.showvars.explore = true;
            $scope.showvars.tourdetail = true;
            break;
        case "tour":
            $scope.showvars.explore = true;
            $scope.showvars.tour = true;
            break;
        case "nearby":
            $scope.showvars.explore = true;
            $scope.showvars.nearby = true;
            break;
        case "info":
            $scope.showvars.explore = false;
            $scope.showvars.info = true;
            break;
        case "search":
            $scope.showvars.search = true;
            break;
        case "return":
            $scope.showvars.explore = true;
            $scope.showvars.info = false;
            $scope.showvars.search = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    console.log($scope.showvars)


}
```

Here is the code, unfortunately it doesn't have a working example.

https://jsfiddle.net/jpking72/61cfyre8/

Comment: Do not use `ng-show` and `ng-hide` at the same time... they both do the same and just have reversed semantics.

Comment: Thank you.   I had a jQuery statement I forgot to delete.   If you want credit you can post your comment as the answer and I'll give you credit.

Comment: So the comment did not help? Then it is not an answer :D